# CMake make install fails with "file INSTALL cannot find <myfile>"

Tags: cmake

I have the following project structure

```
MyProject
CMakeLists.txt
\SubProject1
\SubProject1\CMakeLists.txt
\SubProject2
\SubProject2\CMakeLists.txt
```

Compiling the binaries works fine I just use `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(SubProject1)` etc.

The Config for each SubProject is basically `SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ../Bin)`

So from MyProject Dir I create a Build dir

```
mkdir Build
cd Build
cmake ..
make install
```

my binaries are now in `MyProject/Build/Bin/binaryname`

but the install target fails

When I try to use `cmake` DEB installer with

```
INSTALL(FILES Bin/binaryname DESTINATION /opt/myproject/bin)
```

it fails because `cmake` searches the path in the root dir of my project (due me using `cmake ..` most likely)

So `cmake` tries to use `MyProject/Bin/binaryname`

instead of looking up `Bin/binaryname` in the current working dir

how do I fix this? `../Bin/binary` etc didn't work - and I don't want to hardcode `Build/Bin/binary` into `cmake` - because the directory to build into is free to choose basically

EDIT: Here is a stripped down SubProject1 `CMakeList.txt`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "Source/*.cpp")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("Include")
get_property(inc_dirs DIRECTORY PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(mybinary ${SOURCES})

IF(UNIX)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-fPIC)
ENDIF(UNIX)
```

Comment: Do you have any specific build or test requirement that forces you to move compiled executable files to the ../Bin directory ? Normally, CMake picks executables in their default binary dir and install them using the TARGETS argument of INSTALL.

Comment: No, but that does not help me either. If i remove this, then my binaries are in Build/SubProject1/binary - but when i use INSTALL(TARGETS SubProject1 DESTINATION /opt/myproject/bin) cmake already complains during "cmake .." that it cant find SubProject1

Comment: Could you then please show the relevant bits of the `SubProject1/CMakeLists.txt` file ? I believe the problem might lie in there.

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: Seeing that your executable is named `mybinary` the argument to the INSTALL's TARGETS argument should be `mybinary` too, which should make your comment's attempt work.

Comment: No i get install TARGETS given target "mybinary" which does not exist in this directory. And that also doesnt make sense to add the executeable here - its only there after a compile - but i already get that error during "cmake .."

Comment: Looks like a design flaw http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14444

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake does not support installing from targets defined in sub dirs.

If I want to add files from my build dir I have to change

```
INSTALL(FILES Bin/binaryname DESTINATION /opt/myproject/bin)
```

to

```
INSTALL(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bin/binaryname DESTINATION /opt/myproject/bin)
```

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. It's not because _"`cmake` can't install from a sub-directory,"_ that's just the nature of the beast...